# What does "limited daylight only" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

‘Yes, except this one,’ said Vicki. She crouched down and pointed to a
grubby notice right at the bottom of the mass. Athena bent over. ‘To let,’ it
said. ‘One room, **limited daylight only**, $25 per week. NB house not
communal.’

Does it mean:

1. it is not sunny place toward east?
2. It has not got source of light. and the only source of light is sun during the day?

Source: The Children's Bach by Helen Garner

Comment: It's not an established idiom that I know of, so the only way to understand is through the context.

Comment: I would guess that the only window looks out on the wall of another building, making the room always poorly lit.

Comment: ... or onto (up to?) a nearby hedge of mature Lawson's Cypresses.

Comment: Or a small window in a high ceiling/roof.

Comment: Yeah, it almost certainly has electric light, but not much daylight.

Comment: It means that the room only gets a small amount of natural light during the day. Both of the meanings you suggest are non sequiturs. They are not conclusions you could logically draw based solely on an ad stating, "One room, limited daylight only, $25 per week. NB house not communal."